# Sort a multi-dimensional array in php by "score" rules with php

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array

Good time.

I have a multidimensional array $a like this:

```
$a[0] = [1,5,2022-04-01,2022-04-20, 5, 10:30:00, 11:30:00, 1, 700];
$a[1] = [1,5,2022-04-05,2022-04-15, '', 10:30:00, 11:30:00, 1, 800];
$a[2] = [1,0,2022-04-07,2022-04-15, '', '', '', 1, 800];
$a[3] = [1,5,2022-04-06,2022-04-16, '', '', '', 0, 900];
$a[4] = [1,5,2022-04-07,2022-04-12, '', '', '', 0, 600];
 ...
$a[n] = [1,0,2022-04-06,2022-04-16, 4, '', '', 0, 1100];
```

First four elements in each `$a[]` are always not-empty. Elements from 5 to 7, as you see, can be empty or not. Element 8 can be only 0 or 1, but not empty. And the last element is always not-empty.

I want to sort this multi-dimensional array with some "score" logic:

First rule:

- if we have empty all 5, 6 and 7 elements (like we have in $a[2]) - the score of this $a[] is 1
- if we have empty only 6 and 7 elements, and 5 is not-empty, (like we have in $a[n]) - the score of this $a[] is 2
- if we have empty only 5 element, but 6 and 7 are not-empty (like we have in $a[1]) - the score of this $a[] is 3
- if we have all 5, 6 and 7 elements not-empty (like we have in $a[0]) - the score of this $a[] is 4

Also second rule:

- if score for two $a[] is the same, but 8th element is different, the sorting function have to put one of them with "1" as 8th parameter higher, than another

And last rule:

- if two (or more) $a[] have the same score and and also 8th parameter is the same, the sorting function have to put higher those, that have less difference between 4 and 3 parameter (in fact it is a difference between 2 dates).

So, the result have to be from highest to lowest:

```
[1,5,2022-04-01,2022-04-20, 5, 10:30:00, 11:30:00, 1, 700]; // 4 scores 
[1,5,2022-04-05,2022-04-15, '', 10:30:00, 11:30:00, 1, 800]; //3 scores 
[1,0,2022-04-06,2022-04-16, 4, '', '', 0, 1100]; // 2 scores 
[1,0,2022-04-07,2022-04-15, '', '', '', 1, 800]; // 1 score + 8th parameter is "1" 
[1,5,2022-04-07,2022-04-12, '', '', '', 0, 600]; // 1 score + dates difference is 5 days 
[1,5,2022-04-06,2022-04-16, '', '', '', 0, 900]; // 1 score + dates difference is 10 days
```

How it can be done in php?

Comment: sorry for maybe not-good-looking formatting in my question, i hope that moderator will improve my formatting

Comment: Use `usort()` with a comparison function that calculates the scores for each parameter and compares them.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I found examples of simple comparison function for usort(), like this (in my case, it makes first elements those that have 5th element not-empty: 

`function cmp(array $a, array $b) {
    if ($a[4] > $b[4]) {//first will be with populated value
        return -1;
    } else if ($a[4] < $b[4]) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

usort($a, 'cmp');
var_dump($a);
`

How can i add second rule in this cmp function? For example, if 5th and 6 th and 7th are not-empty, it have be upper in sorted array. Everywhere i find only simple examples

Comment: Write a function that calculates the score. Then you can use `function cmp($a, $b) { return score($a) - score($b); }`.

Comment: It will be a little more complicated because of your last rule, but that's the general idea.

Comment: yes, your last example with returning score($a) - score($b) seems to be good idea, thanks

Comment: So it works fine on php5.6 server, but does not work on php7 server. The sorting runs with  `usort($recordsarr, 'cmp2');` and the cmp2 function is `function cmp2(array $a, array $b) { return (score($b) - score($a)); }`. On php7 server it shows me: "Usort() expects parameter 2 to be a valid callback". I also tried variant with `usort($recordsarr, function($a, $b) {cmp2($a, $b);});`, it does not show an error, but is not sorting - aray remains the same. What i have to fix to make it work on php7 server?

Comment: using `usort($recordsarr, array( $this, "cmp2" ));` fixed the problem

Comment: That would only be necessary if `cmp2` is a class method. If it's an ordinary function you don't need the array.